# I am trying to proxy secure http to kong from nginx but I get an error about http request sent to an HTTP port?

Tags: nginx, kong

Using this config :

```
upstream kong {
  server 127.0.0.1:8000;
}

upstream kong_secure {
  server 127.0.0.1:8443;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.example.co.za;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/api.error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/api.access.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://kong;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}


server {
    server_name api.example.co.za;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/api.error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/api.access.log;


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://kong_secure;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.co.za/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.co.za/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

I get:

```
400 Bad Request
The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port
```

Comment: Use either `proxy_pass http://kong;` or `proxy_pass https://kong_secure;`

Answer (score 0):

Kong is also running nginx, so the error was really coming from kong.
I verified this by checking the access logs.
Nginx vanilla was doing the ssl termination and then proxying to the upstream ssl listening on ssl.

However now it is plain http but going to an https port on kong.

So to fix this set the upsteam to the non https port and remove `kong_secure` it is not needed:

```
upstream kong {
  server 127.0.0.1:8000;
}
```

But now kong will complain with:

```
{"message":"Please use HTTPS protocol"}
```

To fix that you need to read the docs on [Restricting the client protocol](https://docs.konghq.com/1.0.x/proxy/#restricting-the-client-protocol-httphttpstcptls), eventually leading you to set the header `X-Forwarded-Proto: https` and adding the porxy ip to `trusted_ips` in the kong configuration.

Comment: I have the same problem and I tried your solution above but still doesnt work

can you share the update working nginx conf?

Thank you

Comment: @pylady I am still looking for the solution, If you fixed can you share the solution?